# Is there a way to get free mammoth coins?

Tags: brawlhalla

I really love Brawlhalla, and I've been playing it for a good while now. I have a level 21 account, and I'm pretty good, but when I see people with these awesome skins for their character, I always think "Wow, I really wish I could get that skin!"  The problem is that I don't like to spend money on games.  I have already signed up for Grabpoints, and I'm saving up my points for Steam wallet money, but it takes a **lot** of points to get **anything**. So, my question is this: Is there any quick way to get free mammoth coins?

Comment: If there was a quick way, that would kill the business model the developers have created.

Comment: Ok.  Is there **_any_** way to get free mammoth coins besides grabpoints?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so, as I am at approximately your level on PS4 and I can not find a way, so, no.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no free mammoth coins.  I have seen them offer free weapons for subscribing to various social media accounts, awarded as codes you enter into the game (I believe this is how Community Colours work as well), so I suppose it's *possible* that the devs could give out codes for coins as a community reward, but I've been playing for six+ years now and have never seen that happen.